# Decrypting .doc file with syncfusion

Tags: c#, encryption, .doc

I"m trying to open a .doc (word 1997-2003) with Syncfusion, in c#.
I get the following error: "Specified password "x" is incorrect!", while it is correct...
I do not have the same problem with .docx files, so I thought maybe Syncfusion does not support old word files, or the encryption process is different...
I"m encoding the password by Base64 if it matters....
thank you!

Comment: Encrypted read-only (no change allowed) or completely encrypted against read

Comment: completely encrypted against read